# Play mp4 file through php in HTML5 Video Tag in Chrome?

Tags: php, video, mp4

I have a problem with mp4 files. Html5 Video Tag can play it with direct link, but not with PHP Header (Mp3 is worked fine with PHP Header). I have tried almost of solution in Stack but still not resolve my problem :(

Hear is my code:

**PHP**   mp4.php

```
    error_reporting(0);

    $local_file = 'z.mp4';//'b.mp3';
    $download_file = 'out.mp4';
    // send headers
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$download_file);
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    readfile($local_file);
```

**HTML**

```
     <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
          <source src="http://localhost/videos/mp4.php" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
```

I don't know why :( Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK! I've resolved my problem :) Hope this will help anyone has the same problem as me

Just use that code:

```
$file = 'local_file';
$newfile = 'outFile';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($newfile));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you've added unnecessary headers to your php file. Try this one:

```
$local_file = 'z.mp4';
$size = filesize($local_file);

header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Content-Length: ".$size);

readfile($local_file);
```

And a HTML code something like this

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls>
  <source src="mp4.php" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**EDIT:** This will also work for mp3 files when you change Content-Type header and html video type.

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls>
  <source src="mp3.php" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer :)

I've tried it and still not work :( mp3.php and direct link (both mp3 and mp4) works fine, but mp4.php is not

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your mp4 file. Did you try another one?

Comment: Yes, i tried the other files. They also didn't work :)