# HTML5 video tag not working in IE when tested from localhost (XAMP /Apache)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-video

Just as the title says. I've been working on a site and had added a big html video for the main page.

I looked over online...myme types checked, h264 encoding checked. I looked over old versions of the file i've been working on and noticed an old pure HTML file which loaded the video in all browsers with no problem (which I guess discards any encoding or video quality issues)

It all was working neat. Even displaying in firefox, chrome an IE. BUT for some reason the video does not load in IE whenever the file extension for the page it's on is .PHP. To be precise, whenever i try it from my LOCALHOST (XAMP with Apache server)

I also checked the dev tools and under network it does show it as the right content type and no error whatsoever (getting normal 200 result)

Here's the snippet of the video tag used:

```
<div id="video_container">

        <video autoplay loop poster="video.jpg" id="header_vid">               

            <source src="imagenes/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        </video>
```

LOL, and just noticed...not even the poster image is showing in IE...wtf.

I'm so confused, could anyone enlighten me a bit please? Could it be something related to the path used? been digging around the net for days *_*

Comment: possible duplicate of [mp4 from PHP - Not playing in HTML5 Video tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732419/mp4-from-php-not-playing-in-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your url is formed properly when you are using .php extension on IE. Same issue addressed quite a few time here.
[mp4 from PHP - Not playing in HTML5 Video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732419/mp4-from-php-not-playing-in-html5-video-tag)  ||
[Play mp4 file through php in HTML5 Video Tag in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596450/play-mp4-file-through-php-in-html5-video-tag-in-chrome)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't quite understand. I mean, I'm using a php file for other purposes (some includes here and there) but nothing related specifically to the video (i want to load it normally).

How come changing the extension of the page file affects this?

Answer (score 1):

I notice IE doesn't like the properties without value, so try

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" poster="video.jpg" id="header_vid">
```