# PHP video playlist won't load

Tags: php, html, video.js

I'm trying to load a video from another PHP file so it will be like my main playlist

video code:

```
<video id="video" class="video-js" controls="" preload="none" data-setup="{}">
<source src="v.php?video=[video id in playlist]" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

For v.php the code is

```
<?php 

$video = $_GET['video'];

if($video == 1) echo "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Ev9OED5LnZLILAXH_RaOS0Ytdq_LDDglugy_7XmeYJb49Cr5lA7wWQ8XTYIuuagfX74-mgcBDw=m22";
//next video....
?>
```

But it will not load the video.?

P.S. the video is online to test the code

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: it's don't see the video link i get:
`log.js:79 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.`

but when entering the link by localhost:80/v.php?video=1
it show's the link

Comment: I'd guess the php script called by the video src must send back the actual file stream instead of a link? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596450/play-mp4-file-through-php-in-html5-video-tag-in-chrome